# Triggering jQuery UI Autocomplete created in separate JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, automation

**Short Version**
I am trying to trigger jQuery UI Autocomplete and despite my various attempts it fails to register my input. I have tried sending keyboard events, jQuery typing plugins, triggering manually and understand their function but nothing has come to fruition.

**Long Version**
I'm currently working for a company helping them automate input into an external website. I have created a Chrome extension which does several other related task but I have now added a separate function to automate this page. I have used JavaScript in my content script to click certain buttons and fill fields/submit forms which all works well. However, there is one field on the site that implements jQuery Autocomplete (created in the site's JavaScript) and I am having trouble triggering it.

The problem I have is that although may be able to fill in a value that is acceptable, if I don't click it from the list then the form will not register it. This would not be an issue if the autocomplete list actually appeared.

So initially I thought that the problem was that I was just changing the **value** of the field without triggering certain events that would set off the autocomplete. However, the field does not seem to register any keydown, keyup or keypress events that I send using:

```
$(control).trigger("keydown");
```

After this I found several jQuery plugins that simulate typing, specifically [jQuery Autotype](https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype/) and [TypeIt](https://macarthur.me/typeit/). These both simulate the keystrokes of a user supposedly but neither produces any response from the autocomplete.

Next I looked into a stand-alone function that produced typing which I found on Stack Exchange;

```
var txt = "DANTEC";
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
var tb = $("#pageBeanvendorDescription").attr("value", "|");

(function typeIt() {
        var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            char++;
            var type = txt.substring(0, char);
            tb.attr("value", type + '|');
            typeIt();
            if (char == txtLen) {
                tb.attr("value", tb.attr("value").slice(0, -1))
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }
        }, humanize);
    }());
```

This produces a simulation of keyboard typing in the box but also doesn't seem to trigger the autocomplete.

I also read how to trigger autocomplete manually using:

```
$(control).autocomplete("search");
```

However, this also produced an error saying that no autocomplete had been created. I then assumed this was because the content script of the chrome extension was not loading after the page and so the autocomplete had not yet been created so I set the content script to load at the end of document load in the manifest file but still no luck.

I then investigated their autocomplete function itself to see if they were blocking certain triggers but I honestly can't see where they do this. I see the moment where they make the field clear itself on blur and transform lots of input on certain triggers but I can't seem to see how they are blocking my attempts to trigger the autocomplete. I will copy their function at the end.

Therefore, my question is whether I am doing something wrong with my attempted triggers or that you know of another way entirely. I am very interesting to know *why* my methods aren't working.

Here is the function they use to register the autocomplete:

```
/**
 * This function makes a regular text input field to a AutoComplete component.
 * An AutoComplete component affect on 2 fields: the AutoComplete component itself (text field)
 *
 * We using jQuery UI Autocomplete component (1.8.4), for more information look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
 *
 * and another hidden field with the code.
 * @elementId - the id of the input field
 * @fieldCode - the name of the code field (usually hidden). It's the <field_code> value from the XML.
 * @allowFreeText - boolean value, when true the component can include text which is not taken from the Auto-Complete list.
 * @minChars - the minimum number of chars which will send a request.
 */
function registerAutocomplete(elementId, fieldCode, allowFreeText, minChars, delay) {
if ($("#" + elementId).is(":disabled")) return;
fieldName = $("#" + elementId).attr('name');
// the auto-complete widget is first readonly (to support no JavaScript browsers), when
// JavaScript enabled it will be changed here:
$("#" + elementId).removeAttr('readonly');
validValueSelected = true; // true when the value of the field is taken from the list (or from the bean)
lastValue = $("#" + elementId).val();

if (!allowFreeText) {
    // register onBlur and onChange events to reset the field when
    // its value is not taken from the list:
    $("#" + elementId).blur(function() {
        if (!validValueSelected) {
            $('[name=\"' + fieldCode + '\"]').val("");
            $('[name=\"' + fieldName + '\"]').val("");
        }
    });
    $("#" + elementId).change(function() {
        if (lastValue != $("#" + elementId).val()) {
            validValueSelected = false;
        }
    });
}
postUrl = $("#pageForm").attr('action'); // the URL to post the ajax request

$("#" + elementId).on("focus", function() {
    transformInputForLookup($(this));
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) return true;
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "#_#_#");
}).on("change", function(){
    transformInputForLookup($(this));
}).on("keyup", function(){
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        transformInputForLookup($(this));
    }
}).on("blur", function(){
    transformInputForLookup($(this), true);
});

var $ul, $request;
try {
      $("#"+elementId).autocomplete("destroy");
      $("#"+elementId).removeData('autocomplete');
} catch (e) {}
$("#"+elementId).autocomplete({
                    appendTo: $("#"+elementId).getParentForWidget(),
                    source : function(request, response) {
                        fieldName = $("#" + elementId).attr('name');
                        var mergedData = getMergedData(request.term, elementId, fieldName, []);
                        if (request.term === "#_#_#" || $("#"+elementId).val().length < minChars) {
                            $("#"+elementId).removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                            if (mergedData) response(mergedData);
                        } else {
                            var mergedData = getMergedData(request.term, elementId, fieldName, []);
                            if (mergedData && mergedData.length > 0) {
                                response(mergedData);
                                if ($ul) $ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'></li>" +
                                        "<li class=\"ui-autocomplete-category innerLoading noBorder\" style=\"text-align: center\">" +
                                        "<img src=\"/infra/images/jquery-ui/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif\"></img>" +
                                        "</li>");
                            }
                            if ($request) $request.abort();
                            $request = $.ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : postUrl,
                                    dataType : "xml",
                                    timeout : 10000,
                                    // post the whole form:
                                    data: $("#pageForm").add().serialize()+"" +
                                            "&pageBean.ajaxInfo.ajaxRequest=true&pageBean.ajaxInfo.singleField="+fieldName,
                                    success : function(xmlResponse) {
                                            var data = [];
                                            // parse and return the XML response:
                                            element = "autocomplete_"+fieldName.toLowerCase();
                                            element = element.replace(/\./g, '_');
                                            data = $(element, xmlResponse).map(function() {
                                                                                        return {
                                                    label: $("label", this).text() ,
                                                    value: $("key", this).text()
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    });
                                            response(getMergedData(request.term, elementId, fieldName, data)||data);
                                            $("#"+elementId).removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading-error");
                                    },
                                    error : function() {
                                            $("#"+elementId).removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")
                                            $("#"+elementId).addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading-error")
                                            $(".ui-autocomplete-category.innerLoading").remove();
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    },
                    minLength : 1,
                    delay : delay,
                    search : function(event, ui) {
                        $("#"+elementId).removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading-error");
                    },
                    select : function(event, ui) {
                        if (ui.item.value == " ") {
                            ui.item.value = "";
                            ui.item.label = "";
                        }
                        $('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').val(ui.item.value);
                        $('[name=\"'+fieldName+'\"]').val(ui.item.label);
                        lastValue = $("#" + elementId).val();
                        validValueSelected = true;

                        var changeTriggersRefresh = ($('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').attr("onchange")||"").indexOf("ajaxRefresh") > -1;
                        if (changeTriggersRefresh) {
                            $(document).one("pageReady", function() {
                                setTimeout(function(){$('[name=\"'+fieldName+'\"]').focusWithCursorEnd()}, 0);
                            });
                        }

                        if ($('[name=\"'+fieldName+'\"]').parent().find(".improvedPickup,.pickupSH").length === 1
                                && ("" + (ui.item.value||"")).length > 0) {
                            if ($('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').attr("onchange")) setLoadingBlocker(true);
                            initClearPickupButton(elementId);
                            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : $("#pageForm").attr("action"),
                                dataType : "html",
                                timeout : 10000,
                                data: $("#pageForm").serialize() +
                                        "&pageBean.ajaxInfo.ajaxRequest=true&pageBean.ajaxInfo.singleField=" +
                                        "&pageBean.pickupInfo.pickupFieldName=" + fieldName +
                                        "&pageBean.pickupInfo.pickupFieldCode=" + fieldCode +
                                        "&pageBean.pickupInfo.extendedPickupUrlParameters=" +
                                        "&" + fieldName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(ui.item.label) +
                                        "&" + fieldCode + "=" + encodeURIComponent(ui.item.value) +
                                        "&operation=update_pickup_selection_history",
                                success: function() {
                                    populateSelectionHistoryMap(elementId, true);
                                    setLoadingBlocker(false);
                                },
                                complete: function() {
                                    $('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').change();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').change(); //Notify registered event handlers that the value was changed
                        }
                        transformInputForLookup($("#" + elementId));
                        return false; // override the default behavior
                    },
                    open : function() {
                        $("#"+elementId).removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                        validValueSelected = false;
                        var $self = $(this);
                        var term = $self.data("uiAutocomplete").term;
                        var termRe = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "ig");
                        var $acList = $self.data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element;
                        $acList.addClass("opened"); // For slide down transition
                        $acList.attr("id", elementId + "_list");
                        $acList.find("li > a").each(function(){ // Bold highlight
                            if (!term || $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === -1) return true;
                            $(this).html($(this).text().replace(termRe, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
                        });
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                    },
                    focus : function(event, ui) {
                        if (ui.item.value == "")
                            ui.item.label = "";
                        // $('[name='+fieldName+']').val(ui.item.label);
                        $(this).addClass("jsAutoCompleteClass");
                        return false; // override the default behavior
                    },
                    response: function(event, ui) {
                        // Turn on autofocus only when we have 1 item in the list
                        if (ui.content.length === 1) {
                            $(this).autocomplete("option", "autoFocus", true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).autocomplete("option", "autoFocus", false);
                        }
                    },
                    create: function() {
                        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                            $ul = ul;
                            $ul.addClass("dropdown-menu");
                            return $('<li' + (item.category ? ' class="' + item.category + '"' : '') + '>')
                            .append($("<a>").text(item.label)
                                    .append(item.category ? "<i class='uxf-icon uxf-back-in-time selectionHistoryIcon'></i>" : "").html())
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                        };
                        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
                            var that = this,
                            currentCategory = "";
                            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                                var li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                                if ( item.category ) {
                                  li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
                                }
                            });
                            ul.find(".selectionHistoryItem:last").addClass("last");
                        }
                    },
                    close : function() {
        lettersTyped = $('[name=\"'+fieldName+'\"]').val().length;
        // here we reset the field if use didn't choose valid value where not allowing free text.
        // we are checking that (lettersTyped >= minChars) for the following scenario (let's say minChars=3).
        // user start typing 3 letters. The option list is opened. Now he delete the last letter. The list is
        // closed since he didn't type enough letters. In this case we don't want to reset the field.
        if (!allowFreeText && !validValueSelected && lettersTyped >= minChars) {
            // the value is not taken from the list ==> delete it
                            $('[name=\"' + fieldCode + '\"]').val("");
                            $('[name=\"' + fieldName + '\"]').val("");
            $('[name=\"'+fieldCode+'\"]').change();//Notify registered event handlers that the value was changed
                        }
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");

                    }
                }).keypress(function(e) {
            //using triggerHandler and not trigger so that we can return the returned value
            return $('[name=\"' + fieldCode + '\"]').triggerHandler(e);
        });

}
```

Comment: Good first question! My minor feedback is just (1) trim down the code if you can, as that is rather a lot of code to demonstrate an issue - can you create a [smaller example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, (2) keep chatty material to a minimum - I trimmed out quite a bit without hurting the main theme at all. Readers like succinct here. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback! The trouble is that I'm not sure which part of the autocomplete function could be masking the event triggers and so wanted to include it all just in case. I'll make sure to be more to the point with my question the future :)